# What is the preferred fopen mode to open a file using PHP?

Tags: php, file

In what situations would you use `fopen($file, 'a') vs fopen($file, 'a+')` ?

If I am writing a class to handle the creation and writing to, of files and I use the mode '+a' does that mean after a write I can immediately read? Are there any implications like file fragmentation? The mode 'a' allows write only, which means the file will only accept writes. In that case I would need to close the file then open it again if I want to read it.

Comment: The best mode is the one that does what you want. Each one does something different. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for the specifics of each one.

Comment: After you write you'll need to use `fseek()` if you want to read. Otherwise you'll try to read at the end of the file, and there won't be anything there.